# If P(Q)R and Q(R)S → P(R)S.

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

I was hoping that you might be able to help me. I have been working on problem 2.1.4 from a textbook called “Thinking Geometrically, a Survey of Geometries” for several days and I'm not sure how to proceed. In this chapter, we are introduced to the concept of minimalistic axiom systems. In this particular problem, we are given the following axioms where P(Q)R signifies that Q is between P and R.
(i) If P(Q)R, then R(Q)P. 
(ii)If P(Q)R, then ~P(R)Q and P ≠ R. 
(iii)There are at least two distinct points. 
(iv)For any two points P and Q there is a point R so that P(Q)R.
(v) If P(Q)R and Q(R)S → P(R)S.

I need to prove parts a.) and c.)

(a) If P(Q)R and Q(R)S, prove that P(Q)S. 
(c) Use induction to prove that for all-natural numbers n there are at least n points.

The professor hinted that we must place a point (let's call it O) to the left of P such that O(P)Q to prove part a.). Lastly, we have already proved some theorems from these axioms that we can use in this problem. These are:
Theorem 2.1.1. For three points A, B, and C, if A(B)C, then ~C(A)B, ~B(C)A, and ~B(A)C.
Theorem 2.1.2. For three points A, B, and C, if A(B)C, then A, B, and C are distinct points.
Theorem 2.1.3. There are at least four distinct points.

Answer (score 0):

A.  p(q)r, q(r)s.  Thus s(r)q, r(q)p.  Hence s(q)p, p(q)s.

B.  Base step. Distinct p,a,q with p(a)q.
Induction step.
Assume distinct p,a$_1,.. $a$_n$,q with
p(a$_1$)a$_2$,.. a$_{n-1}$(a$_n$)q.
Show exists b /= a$_n$, q with a$_n$(b)q.